# delete prefix y in an array to use it ax axis for a graph

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I took a row from a database with php and mysql and put it in a the array $dataPoints6. Then i transfered it with json-encode in an js array.
In Generel I want to use this array for data part of a line graph.
The problem (checked with console.log) is, that there is always an y in every array part. See here 
( :{y: "39"})

How can I delete this y?  Without this y I can use an array for the x or y axis in a line graph. Here is my Code. Thx for your help.

```js
 <?php
   
 $dataPoints6 = array();
 try{
     // Creating a new connection.
    // Replace your-hostname, your-db, your-username, your-password according to your database
    $link = new \PDO(   'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=alurhbuj3;charset=utf8mb4', //'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=canvasjs_db;charset=utf8mb4',
                        'cu7iymbi1b', //'root',
                        'Thomas100388', //'',
                        array(
                            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                            \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
                        )
                    );
    
    $handle6 = $link->prepare("select y from Lt_data where nr=1"); 
    $handle6->execute(); 
    $result6 = $handle6->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  
    foreach($result6 as $row6){
        array_push($dataPoints6, array($row6));
    }
   
    
 $link = null;
    
}
catch(\PDOException $ex){
  
}


?>

 <script>
 var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints6); ?>;
   
   var a =[2,4,6,8,10];
    console.log(js_array);
var trace1 = {
  x: a, 
  y: [1,2,3,4,5], 
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4], 
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9], 
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout1 = {
  yaxis: {rangemode: 'tozero',
          showline: true,
          zeroline: true}
};

var layout2 = {
  yaxis: {rangemode: 'tozero',
           
          zeroline: true}
};

Plotly.newPlot('div1', data, layout1);

Plotly.newPlot('div2', data, layout2);
</script>
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thx. It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you only need the array of values without key. as you have created your dummy arrays in javascript. I would suggest you should add the value from the database directly into the $dataPoints6 array as follows.

```
foreach($result6 as $row6){
    $dataPoints6[] = $row6->y;
}
```

This way you will get your array same as your javascript array

```
a =[2,4,6,8,10];
```